# How to restrict/define the type of control.value (AbstractControl)

Tags: angular

I'm using form builder/reactive forms and I need to validate a custom component that has non primitive type values, the component is an input box + dropdown select.

```
this.dataForm = this.fb.group({
  name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]],
  description: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(10)]],
  amount: [0, InputDropdownValidation.validateRange(0, 10)], // <<< Custom component
  cost: [0]
});
```

I've got a validator working on the input, it implements `ControlValueAccessor` to work with the reactive form. Now I want it to validate the type of object I'm using for this component's value: `InputDropdownItem` rather than just the input.

```
static validateRange(min, max) {
  return function (control: AbstractControl) {
    if (control.value < min || control.value > max) {
      return { outOfRange: true };
    }
    return null;
  };
}
```

I can use this

```
console.log('validator prop = ', control.value.input);    
console.log('validator prop = ', control.value.dropdownItem);
```

I'd like some sort of definition so that function only works with controls that have values of type `InputDropdownItem`. So if a developer did this:

```
console.log('validator prop = ', control.value.nonExistingProp); // undefined
```

It'd catch it in the compiler first.

**Component for amount:**

```
  value: InputDropdownItem;

  // ...

  onInputChange(input: any) {
    this.value.input = input;
    this.valueChange.emit(this.value);
    this.propagateChange(this.value);
  }

  onDropdownChange(dropdownItem: DropdownItem) {
    this.value.dropdownItem = dropdownItem;
    this.valueChange.emit(this.value);
    this.propagateChange(this.value);
  }
```

**The InputDropdownItem**

```
export class InputDropdownItem {
  input: any;
  dropdownItem: DropdownItem;
}
```

Comment: If the value is of type InputDropdownItem, then why are you passing `0` as initial value when creating the control (`amount: [0, ...]`), and why are you comparing the value with min and max, since the value is supposed to be an InputDropdownItem and not a number?

Comment: I was using that before i did the InputDropdown component, It's meant to be InputDropdownItem

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're asking, and why you're showing us that code if you know it's not correct. Anyway; a FormControl is not (yet) a ganeric type, and its value is of type any. So it's your responsibility to know what the actual type of the value is. So you need to do something like `const item: InputDropdownItem = control.value;`

Comment: Thats the question, I don't want to have to know what the actual type is, I want validateRange(min, max) to only be able to be applied to controls with values of type InputDropdownItem. Can you please put full answer with code.

Comment: Though there might be something Typescripty to use, I'll just have to check for undefined or typeof

Comment: or if property exists